# On iPadOS 14, what does this box on the today view do?

Tags: ipados, widgets

2019 iPad, running the new release of iPadOS 14. When adding widgets to the today view, there is a box at the top that says:

> Drag your favourite widgets here to pin them on the Home Screen.

[image]

Any widgets I place in this box behave no differently to the ones underneath, so what is this box supposed to enable? It doesn’t matter if I have the “Keep on Home Screen” option checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets placed in the ‘favourites’ section remain on the home screen when other widgets below are hidden.

To see the difference between the widget sections, place a widget in the favourite section, tap Done, then scroll the list of widgets beyond the top to push the bottom widgets off screen. Let go and the bottom widgets will remain hidden while favourite widgets will remain. Scroll the list down to show the other widgets again.

Comment: If that is what is supposed to happen, it certainly isn’t what *does* happen. Vid: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZBVj5XZdvlad599P2R4T3SgCCOq2HsYjpDk

Comment: @Darren Scroll up, beyond the top, as if you're trying to look at something above the time and date, then let go.

Comment: Ah, so doing that makes them all disappear except the pinned ones. Thanks for the info, but what a bloody useless, and poorly explained feature this is!